# CKAN search by custom field

Tags: ckan

In my ckan (ckan.org) setup I want to add custom field, which I can use also for searching/filtering, to datasets. For example, open dataset view, click "manage", add something to custom field (key and value), "update dataset" and You can see it in dataset view page. But I cannot see custom field keys in search results, or any way to sort/filter by their values.

So how on Earth am I supposed to be using the custom fields?

Comment: This is a good question, and I wish I knew the answer.  Maybe if you can guess the internal field name used, you can search using `field_name:value`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for an administrator of a CKAN site to add custom fields to datasets: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html

You create a 'CKAN extension' to put this customization (and any others you do) into. Then you use the `IDatasetForm` extension point to add the new field to the dataset schema, choosing any validation to be done on the field. Then you create a couple of snippets of HTML that will show the field in the dataset form and when you view the dataset.